# Where to create threads in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create in my server threads that make some heavy work. Now I create them in the application controller, in the first browser request. I comunicate them with others request with global variables. Its sure there is an elegant way to do this.

I try to create threads in application.rb. But when I do a request the threads stops.

The thread has to get a image from a image server and convert it to png. Thats why it has to be a thread that survives between request.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are Gems like [DelayedJobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) to do this kind of background jobs.

Creating threads yourself in a controller is not recommended, because that might result in memory leaks and makes you vulnerable through DDoS attacks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have read about sidekiq. I think its very usefull but I dont know if with it I can create a thread that makes a loop. In the examples I have read you call the thread in the controller. In my case I want to create the thread when I start the server and then in the controller ask for an image.Again thank you very much.